# Get a particular data from a Json string

Tags: json

I have this json response from a third part server:

```
$jsonResponse = {"errors":[],"param_errors":[{"errors":[{"desc":"the email jb004@gmail.com is already registered by another account","code":"account_mail_is_used"}],"name":"account.mail"}],"code":"BAD_REQUEST","object":"error"}
```

I want to fetch only the text that says the email is already registered. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

```
$jsonResponse.paramErrors.forEach(function(paramError) {
    paramError.errors.forEach(function(error) {
         if(error.code==='account_mail_is_used')
         {
         // error found, do what u want with this error
            console.log(error.code, error.desc);
         }
    }
}
});
```